# convert Youtube URL into Embed iframe in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
                     <div class="row">
                      <div class="input-field col s12">
                        <input id="p_video" type="url" name="p_video_link" type="url">
                        <label for="p_video">Post Video</label>
                      </div>
                    </div>
```

Am New to codeigniter ...
I have to convert  this url box url to embed ocde to store in database via codeigniter ... How to do that...........Thanks in Advance

Comment: While this question is tagged under `php` and `codeigniter`, all I see is some HTML and lot's of `...................`. What have you tried?

Comment: I am tried to convert and store Youtube URL into database as a iframe format ... And then am trying to show the video in ADMIN panel ......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just save the youtube url in database, with out the iframe format but when you retrive the url from database , you save the result in $youtubeurl var and echo in the html, you do something like

```
<?php 

echo '<iframe width="560" height="315" src="'.$youtubeurl.'" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>'; 

?>
```

so it's just concatenate the html with the variable '.$youtubeurl.'